# How to make a condition in subquery based on outer query?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I work on Airbnb like app. I have a `Flat` model and `Price` model, prices have different types of priority which allows customers create a flexible price range.

I stuck with one complicated query. This query should return Flats by date range and calculate prices for this range.

---

Here the part of my models:

```
class Flat(models.Model):
    prices = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Price'
        related_name='flats'
    )
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ...

class Price(models.Model):
    PRIORITY_CHOICES = ((i, i) for i in range(1, 6))

    priority = PositiveIntegerField(choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

---

So far I figure it out how to annotate prices with higher priority by each day. I wrote a custom manager for Flat:

```
class FlatManager(models.Manager):

    def with_prices(self, start, end):
        days = get_days(start, end) # utils function return list of days
        prices = {}
        for day in days:
            prices[str(day)] = models.Subquery(
            Price.objects.filter(
                flats=models.OuterRef('pk')).
                filter(start_date__lte=day, end_date__gte=day).
                order_by('-priority').
                values('price')[:1]
        )
        return self.annotate(**price_dict)
```

---

***Here is my problem***:

Some dates in the `Flat` can be without price blocks, so Flat have its own `price` field for cases when customer don't won't to use flexible prices.  I don't know where I need to add a condition operator in my query. If I add it in the `Price` subquery then I don't be able to use `Outref('price')` because of nesting. 
When I solve it, calculate the sum of aggregated values will not be so complicated for me I think.

Please give some hints at least, I really stuck with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the condition to main query, check if subquery return `None` then use `Flat` model field.
For one `date` value it'll look like this:

```
day = # some date
price = Price.objects.filter(
            flats=models.OuterRef('pk')).
            filter(start_date__lte=day, end_date__gte=day).
            order_by('-priority').
            values('price')[:1])
Flat.objects.annotate(price_block=Subquery(price).annotate(
    derived_price = Case(
                      When(price_block__isnull=True, then='price'),
                      default=F('price_block')
    ))
```

So the `derived_price` value will contain `price` value from `Price` model or `price` value from `Flat` model if subquery returns `None`
But in my case I have a range of dates, so I need subquery and condition for each date. Also I need a sum of all annotated prices.
Here is how I did it:

```
class FlatManager(models.Manager):

    def _construct_conditions(self, keys):
        # Function construct conditions 
        # like in previous example for each date in range
        annotations = {}
        for key in keys:
            condition = {'{}__isnull'.format(key): True, 'then': 'price'}
            annotations['derived_{}'.format(key)] = Case(When(**condition), default=F(key))
        return annotations

    def _add_prices(self, keys):
        values = [F('derived_{}'.format(key)) for key in keys]
        return sum(values)

    def with_prices(self, start, end):
        days = get_days(start, end) # utils function return list of days
        prices = {}
        for num, day in enumerate(days):
            prices['price_{}'.format(num)] = Subquery(
                Price.objects.filter(
                flats=OuterRef('pk')).
                filter(start_date__lte=day, end_date__gte=day).
                order_by('-priority').
                values('weekend_price' if day.weekday() in [4, 5] else 'price')[:1] 
                # also add a condition for weekend price
        )
        return (self.annotate(**prices).
                annotate(**self._construct_conditions(prices.keys())).
                annotate(sum=self._add_prices(prices.keys()))
                )
```